# DB2 SQL - How can I display nothing instead of a hyphen when the result of my case statement is NULL?

Tags: sql, db2

All,

I'm writing a query that includes a CASE statement which compares two datetime fields. If Date B is > Date A, then I'd like the query to display Date B. However, if Date B is not > Date A, then the user who will be getting the report created by the query wants the column to be blank (in other words, not contain the word 'NULL', not contain a hyphen, not contain a low values date). I've been researching this today but have not come up with a viable solution so thought I'd ask here. This is what I have currently:

```
CASE
  WHEN B.DTE_LNP_LAST > A.DTE_PROC_ACT
  THEN B.DTE_LNP_LAST
  ELSE ?
  END AS "DATE OF DISCONNECT"
```

If I put NULL where the ? is, then I get a hyphen (-) in my query result. If I omit the Else statement, I also get a hyphen in the query result. ' ' doesn't work at all. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Typically the way nulls are displayed is controlled by the client software used to display query results. If you insist on doing that in SQL, you will need to convert the date to a character string:

```
CASE
  WHEN B.DTE_LNP_LAST > A.DTE_PROC_ACT
  THEN VARCHAR_FORMAT(B.DTE_LNP_LAST)
  ELSE ''
END AS "DATE OF DISCONNECT"
```

Replace `VARCHAR_FORMAT()` with the formatting function available in your DB2 version on your platform, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the coalesce function

```
Coalesce (column, 'text')
```

If the first value is null, it will be replaced by the second one.